# Have IntelliJ determine if code is only used by tests

Tags: intellij-idea

Can IntelliJ's code analysis options be configured so that it can tell me if code is only used by tests (mostly unit tests) so that I can remove what is essentially dead code from the project.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Specify the scope of your analysis to "Project Production Files", and untick "Include test sources".  This will skip any unit tests that are in folders labeled as "test".

Comment: Any hints on how to do this in modern versions?

Comment: @FilipHaglund It's still the same; run the "Unused declaration" inspection with these options.  You can use the Actions shortcut (default ⌘+⇧+A on Mac OS) to find "Run Inspection by Name" and type that name there.